# How can I get the current controller from within a MVC HtmlHelper extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Like with most implementations of MVC, all of my abstract services are available in the Controller. Well, I am creating the following HTML helper extension to allow embedding application settings into the HTML as hidden inputs:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForSetting<TResult>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<IMyAppSettings, TResult>> expression, string name = null)
{
    IMyAppSettings settings = null;

    return MyHtmlHelpers.HiddenForSetting<IMyAppSettings, TResult>(htmlHelper, expression, settings, name);
}
```

The helper provides the settings object and allows the consumer to select which property to embed. `IMyAppSettings` is such a service. So I want to get this service off of the controller itself. Is there a means of accessing the controller from within this static helper extension method?

**Note: I DO NOT need the controller name! I need the controller instance itself.**

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection for your app? If yes, did you try 'Parameter Injection' to your helper extension to get instance of `IMyAppSettings`?

Comment: Our application uses dependency injection. The controller base class provides an implementation of `IMyAppSettings` that is injected into its constructor. I'm not familiar with parameter injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the controller using:

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller
```

It's a `ControllerBase`.  If you know the type of controller, you can cast it as needed.

Comment: This does not work in .net core. htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller does not exist. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @AntonK Asking here won't do you any good.  Ask a question by scrolling to the top of the page and clicking the big blue "Ask a question" button.